# Jquery plugin that can crop external images

Tags: jquery, image, crop, resize-crop

I am trying to crop Lazyload image to correct size. I have simple jquery plugin given below that can resize and crop the image to correct size by tweaking the image url. This jQuery code automatically crop the image to the correct size after Lazyload plugin load images. But it's not able to crop all images, it crop only one from all images.

*Fiddle*: http://jsfiddle.net/e0myc0po/4/ 
*See that it has cropped only image no 3 !*

**JS:**

*External Resources*: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyloadxt/1.0.5/jquery.lazyloadxt.js

```
$.extend($.lazyLoadXT, {
    onload:myfunc
});

function myfunc(){
    var w = 200;
var h = 150;
$('#crop').find('img').each(function(n, image){
  var image = $(image);
  image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s' + w + '-h' + h +'-c')});
  image.attr('width',w);
  image.attr('height',h);
 });
}

function myfunc(){
    var w = 200;
var h = 150;
$('#another-crop').find('img').each(function(n, image){
  var image = $(image);
  image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s' + w + '-h' + h +'-c')});
  image.attr('width',w);
  image.attr('height',h);
 });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
1
<div id="crop">
<img data-src=""/>
</div>
<br/>
2
<div id="crop">
<img data-src=""/>
</div>
<br/>
3
<div id="another-crop">
<img data-src=""/>
</div>
<br/>
4
<div id="another-crop">
<img data-src=""/>
</div>
```

So my question is why it's not crop all images and what is the solution is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. You've got two or more ID's of an HTML tag and two declaration of function myfunc(). The ID of any tag element on a single page should be unique!! :)

```
<div id="crop">
....
<div id="crop-foo">
....
<div id="crop-something-else">
```

Change id="crop" to class="crop" and then in JS #crop to .crop 
Same goes with: #another-crop / id="another-crop" - change it to a class

Also make one myFunc()

```
function myfunc(){
    var w = 200;
var h = 150;
$('#crop').find('img').each(function(n, image){
  var image = $(image);
  image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s' + w + '-h' + h +'-c')});
  image.attr('width',w);
  image.attr('height',h);
 });
$('#another-crop').find('img').each(function(n, image){
  var image = $(image);
      image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s' + w + '-h'         + h +'-c')});
  image.attr('width',w);
  image.attr('height',h);
 });
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/e0myc0po/6/

Comment: You mean it’s will not works with id? But I have different class and different ids on same page that I have crop, means I have to implement this code for different class and different ids on same page. How I should do?

Comment: And i have to different size of images of different class and different ids on same page, what I should do?

Comment: Name a class "size-one" and for each .size-one change size of an image to some width and height.
Name another div class "size-two" and analogically change sizes of images with this class to preferred.

Comment: I have followed, but it has cropped image number 3 and 4 only. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e0myc0po/8/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e0myc0po/10/  Simpliest solution. Changed function name to myfunc2() and triggered it in myfunc()

Comment: Look's ok. But I was only suppose to answer Your main question. :) Not to do Your whole work. :) Read, learn, experiment and get experience and knowledge till You will fully understand what You are doing! :) If You will get some trouble (like Your main question) Stackoverflow will be happy to help You! :) So don't mind posting some real issues here. 
Good luck and take care! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to define same function twice. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3xphkmsq/ you just have to mention a `class` instead of `id`

Comment: You mean it’s will not works with id? But I have different class and different ids on same page that I have crop, means I have to implement this code for different class and different ids on same page. How I should do?

Comment: you can do multiple id select `$("#crop,#crop1,#crop2").find()`. This way you don't have to define your function again and again for every id.

Comment: And i have to different size of images of different class and different ids on same page, what I should do?

Comment: I have followed, but it has cropped image number 3 and 4 only. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e0myc0po/8/

Comment: because your overriding `myfunc` as I told you don't define the function twice with same name. see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kaz6gv51/

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898651/remove-specific-class-after-this-jquery-plugin